# Interpreting zero-mean Gaussian noise in the context of Kalman Filters

Tags: kalman-filters, gaussian

Consider an object moving in 2D space with constant speed $v_x$,$v_y$. If its  acceleration is modelled as zero-mean Gaussian $ a_x \sim N(0,\sigma_{a_x}^2)$ and $ a_y \sim N(0,\sigma_{a_y}^2)$ within each time step $\Delta t$.

In my understanding it means that if we were to take samples of either $a_x$ or $a_y$ several times within the same time step $\Delta t$, the mean of the sampled values will be approximately zero, and the variance will be approximately $\sigma_{a_x}^2$ or $\sigma_{a_y}^2$.

Is my interpretation right?

If the interpretation is right then how should the equation for updating the position be written?
$$ 
x_{new} = x_{old} + v_x * \Delta t \\
y_{new} = y_{old} + v_y * \Delta t
$$

OR

$$ 
x_{new} = x_{old} + v_x * \Delta t +  {1 \over 2} a_x*\Delta t^2 \\
y_{new} = y_{old} + v_y * \Delta t +  {1 \over 2} a_y*\Delta t^2
$$

As I understand it, the mean value of the accelerations is zero, so the accelerations should have no overall impact on the position. However the variances are non-zero so the variances should affect the variances of the position, let's call them $\sigma_x^2$ and $\sigma_y^2$.

$$
\sigma_{x_{new}}^2 = \sigma_{x_{old}}^2 + {1 \over 4}\sigma_{a_x}^2*\Delta t^4  \\
\sigma_{y_{new}}^2 = \sigma_{y_{old}}^2 + {1 \over 4}\sigma_{a_y}^2*\Delta t^4 
$$

Comment: Generally, what you say is just the statement that $a$ follows a Gaussian distribution when sampled.

Comment: You need to decide where you model starts: does it start in continuous-time? Or does it start in discrete-time?  If it starts in continuous-time, you will then have to decide how you are converting all the system parameters and measurements from continuous-time to discrete-time.  IMHO, the acceleration feeds into the velocity as an additive noise term; you only need to model the impact of velocity on your displacement... and there will be similar equations for converting from $v_{old}$ to $v_{new}$ as you have for converting from $x_{old}$ to $x_{new}$.